# MAC os service for usb insertion and removal

Tags: macos, launchd, launch-daemon, launch-agent

i am trying to create a service for mac that triggers a python file whenever a usb is inserted or ejected in the system. My code works for this functionality but when i shut down my pc and restart the device the service randomly triggers the python script even when i have not inserted any usb.

```
launchctl_daemon_usb_trigger(){
    plist_name=$1
    plist_path="$plist_name.plist"
    plist_filename=$(basename "$plist_path")
    install_path="/Library/LaunchDaemons/$plist_filename"
    trigger_name=$2

    # echo "installing launchctl plist: $plist_path --> $install_path"
    log_message "Service Name <'$plist_name'>"
    log_message "Install Path <'$install_path'>"
    log_message "Setting up trigger event named <'$trigger_name'>."
    log_message "Creating the launchd service <'$plist_path'>."
    log_message "Executing command: <$PYTHON3_DIRECTORY $ETC_PYTHON_ENV $trigger_name>"

# Set the content of the plist file
cat <<EOF | sudo tee "$install_path" > /dev/null
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>$plist_name</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>$PYTHON3_DIRECTORY</string>
        <string>$ETC_PYTHON_ENV</string>
        <string>$trigger_name</string>
        <string>$ORGANIZATION_NAME</string>
        <string>$DEPARTMENT_NAME</string>
        <string>$SECTION_NAME</string>
    </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>$DESTINATION_WORKING_DIRECTORY</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Volumes</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>$LOG_SERVICE_DIRECTORY/$plist_name.out</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>$LOG_SERVICE_DIRECTORY/$plist_name.err</string>
</dict>
</plist>
EOF
    #giving the nescessary permissions
    sudo chown root "$install_path"
    sudo chmod 644 "$install_path"

    #unload the service first
    # echo "unloading the service"
    sudo launchctl unload "$install_path" > /dev/null 2>&1

    #load the service first
    # echo "loading the service"
    sudo launchctl load "$install_path" > /dev/null 2>&1

    log_message "Done creating the launchd service <'$plist_path'>."
}
```

Comment: This will be a fairly unreliable way of doing it, and you should expect plenty of false positives. Note also that network mounts, disk images, and other non-USB storage volumes will show up in `/Volumes/`. You may want to edit your question to explain *precisely* what problem you're trying to solve and we can suggest possible solutions. For example, you can add USB IOKit matching dictionaries as launch events (though you'll need to query the XPC events in the launched agent, I'm not sure if that's possible from Python), or you could use Disk Arbitration to watch for volume mount/unmount events